# How to cancel all after() object in Python tkinter (or customtkinter)?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I am making a personal Python app from `customtkinter` and `tkinter`. But I wonder how I can cancel all `after()` object.
I know, I could just declare an `after()` object with a variable and then use `after_cancel()`. But doing that will make me have to create a lot of variables and struggle to manage them. I tried to search Google and even asked an AI but no help. Any help is appreciated.

---

This is my code (not the original one that I'm working on, just a simplified example):

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
mainLabel = Label(root, text="Closing in 3 seconds...")
mainLabel.pack()

root.after(1000, lambda: mainLabel.configure(text='This is an example text...'))
root.after(1500, lambda: mainLabel.configure(text='1234567890'))
root.after(2125, lambda: mainLabel.configure(text='qwertyuiop'))
root.after(3000, root.destroy)
root.mainloop()
```

Well, I can just declare all those `after()` objects with variables (such as  **`after_obj = root.after(...)`**) and then cancel it (**`root.after_cancel(after_obj)`**). But I can't do that with such many `after()` objects like this. So my question is, is there anyway to cancel all those `after()` objects?

Also, the code that I was running on uses `customtkinter` instead of `tkinter`. And there are a few differences between them. But I think the solution would be the same for both.

Comment: You don't need a separate variable for each `after()` result, you can append them all to a single list, then loop over that list to cancel them all.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you! It worked. But I wonder if there is any other method to cancel all `after()` objects.

Comment: No, even in tcl / to you have to iterate over a list of identifiers to cancel them all.